# Regular Expression What is Matched

Tags: java, regex

Let's say you have a regular expression like this:

```
\d+\.?\d* (mg |teaspoon |mcg |tablet |units |puffs |tab )*(\d )*(P\.O\. )*((once )*daily|B\.I\.D\.*|(once )*a day|Q\.I\.D\.|nightly|P\.R\.N\.|T\.I\.D\.|every (other )*(day|morning))
```

Which matches a variety of expressions including:

> 1 teaspoon once daily
>   1.5 mg
>   10 mg 1 P.O. nightly

etc.

What I'm trying to understand is given that say 1.5 mg and 1.5 mg daily are matches, will a java regular expression always match to the longest string?

Comment: Gut tells me that it will match anything that the pattern mandates.  Is it not?  What behavior are you seeing with that input?

Comment: Have you seen http://refiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Depending on the application, consider using a Natural Language Parser, such as FreeLing, to convert the tokens into part-of-speech tags, then extract the information using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if the rest of the pattern matches with the longer String, the longest String will be returned, instead of the shortest one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "\\d+.?\\d* (mg |teaspoon |mcg |tablet |units |puffs |tab )(\\d )(P.O. )*((once )daily|B.I.D.|(once )a day|Q.I.D.|nightly|P.R.N.|T.I.D.|every (other )(day|morning))";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("1.5 mg 10 mg 1 P.O. nightly");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

Prints: **10 mg 1 P.O. nightly**

Answer (score 2):

With the expression you currently have it will actually not match "1.5 mg" because the last group which defines the frequency is not optional.

To answer your question in more general terms, if you have a string that would match a regular expression and a substring of that string would also match, **it depends entirely on the regular expression which one will be matched**.

For example with the string "foobar", you would match the entire string using the regex `foo(bar)*`, but would only match "foo" with the regex `foo(bar)*?`.

If you want to make sure that the largest string is always matched, make sure that with alternation you always put longer elements first, for example `(foobar|foo)` instead of `(foo|foobar)`.  You will also probably want to avoid using lazy repetition like `*?`, `+?`, or `??`.

Of course these are just some general guidelines, thoroughly test and refactor your regex until you get the expected result in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

> will a java regular expression always match to the longest string?

No.  A regular expression will not always match the longest string since regex libraries usually stop once they have found a match without backtracking to look for a longer match.

For example,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a|aa");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaa");
while (m.find()) { System.out.println(m.group()); }
```

will print

```
a
a
a
```

not

```
aa
a
```

---

This also affects group matching.

One place where this leads to confusion is when people are trying to use regular expressions to match lists of identifiers in alphabetic order, doing something like

```
Pattern.compile("<(/?)(a|b|p|pre|s|script)[^>]*>")
```

to match tags.  Given the input `"<script>Not text in an s tag</script>"`, group 2 will contain `"s"`, not `"script"`.